# Does the iPod Touch calendar support every other day scheduling?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, calendar

Does the iPod Touch calendar support every other day scheduling?

Comment: Could you explain the question further?

Comment: @sentinel Sure.  When I had Windows Mobile & Palm I used to be able to say, "Schedule this same appointment every 2 days" and then it would be every other day.

iOS4 doesn't do that (in the default calendar app anyway), though you can make recurring events, you can't specify every how many days.  Of course I could enter them myself, but I'm using a computer.

Comment: Well then, you answered your question yourself. The provided calendar app does not support "every n days". Maybe there is a different app supporting this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set that up, but not on the device. There's no interface to more complex recursion rules in the iOS calendar app.

If you're synching with iCal on a mac, you add the event to iCal and go into the "custom" recurrence settings, and it's easy to have it repeat every two days.

Sync your device and bob's your uncle.

Comment: Yeah, after I figured out how to sync it with Google Calendar, that did the trick.  Google Calendar allows such <sarcasm>advanced</sarcasm> functionality

Comment: To be fair, it's a tiny little touch interface. On a screen that size, you've got to make some functionality sacrifices or your app starts to look like a christmas tree--all sorts of little doodads hanging off it.